# Nested method in java?

Tags: java, android

How do I go about setting up a nested class / method in java so that I can call them like this:

```
SessionManager client = new SessionManager();
client.session.login("user","password", etc...);
client.profile.update("John", "15", etc...);
client.inventory.add("Potato", etc...);
client.inventory.delete(15, etc...);
```

instead of lumping the methods in just a class:

```
SessionManager client = new SessionManager();
client.login("user","password", etc...);
client.profileUpdate("John", "15", etc...);
client.inventoryAdd("Potato", etc...);
client.inventoryDelete(15, etc...);
```

Comment: Are you looking for a [static inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)?

Comment: Can i not touch static?

Comment: I am not getting you.

Comment: Using `UpperCase` variable names instead of `camelCase` makes questions like this much harder to read for Java developers.

Comment: why does it need to be a nested/inner class? `client.inventory.add(x)` would work even when `inventory` is an instance of an unrelated class.

Comment: My bad, let me digest the article u linked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add public attributes to your SessionManager class, namely Session, Profile, Inventory which each point to their own class and move your methods to the respecive classes.

e.g.

```
public class Session {
   public void login(...){...}
}
```

and

```
public class SessionManager {
    public Session session = new Session();
    ...
}
```

If you desire, Session could be a static inner class of your SessionManager.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, nested methods are not possible, but you can do this:

```
class Sample {
    void sampleMethod() {
        class InnerSample {
            void sampleInnerMethod() {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we define classes inside of methods?

Comment: yes you can absolutely define classes inside of methods..!! @Thilo

Comment: @Thilo Java 8 allows local classes, I think. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html

Comment: Local classes have been around for a while, it seems. In almost 20 years of Java, I've never seen them in the wild ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public class Example {    
    public static class InnerClass {

    }    
}
```

After declaring the classes like that you can reference them like this:

```
Example.InnerClass someInstance = new Example.InnerClass();
```

**But** notice the `static` modifier of the `InnerClass`? `static` in this context means that the `InnerClass` acts like it were defined in its own file. `InnerClass` with `static` cannot access any members of `Example` or call any non-static methods of `Example`, so something like this would be impossible:

```
public class Example { 

    private String someMember;

    private void someMethod() {

    }   

    public static class InnerClass {

        public InnerClass() {
            // Not possible, would throw a compile time error
            doSomething(someMember);
            someMethod();
        }
    }    
}
```

If you don't declare the `InnerClass` static than it essentially becomes a part of `Example` an cannot exist independently. In other words if you don't declare it static than you always need an `Example` instance first and in that instance you can create `InnerClass` objects. However without static it would be possible to access members of `Example` or call methods from `Example`:

```
public class Example { 

    private String someMember;

    private void someMethod() {

    }  

    public class InnerClass {

        public InnerClass() {
            // This is now possible. But you cannot create 
            // an independent `InnerClass` instance anymore
            doSomething(someMember);
            someMethod();
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String result(String[] parts){

    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        if (parts[i].contains("-")) {
            str += result(parts[i].split("-"));
            continue;
        }
        try {
            switch (parts[i]) {
                case ("one"):
                    str += "1";
                    break;
                case ("two"):
                    str += "2";
                    break;
                case ("three"):
                    str += "3";
                    break;
                case ("four"):
                    str += "4";
                    break;
                case ("five"):
                    str += "5";
                    break;
                case ("six"):
                    str += "6";
                    break;
                case ("seven"):
                    str += "7";
                    break;
                case ("eight"):
                    str += "8";
                    break;
                case ("nine"):
                    str += "9";
                    break;
                case ("zero"):
                    str += "0";
                    break;
                case ("plus"):
                    str += "+";
                    break;
                case ("minus"):
                    str += "-";
                    break;
                case ("multiply"):
                    str += "*";
                    break;
                case ("divide"):
                    str += "/";
                    break;
                case "open":
                    str += "(";
                    break;
                case "close":
                    str += ")";
                    break;
                default:
                    if (!(parts[i].equals("curly") || parts[i].equals("brace") || parts[i].equals("by"))) {
                        throw new Exception("Will fix this later");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: On input you have something like "one", "plus", "two-two", I invoke function from itself to parse "two-two" expression.

Comment: Great! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55319170/edit) to include relevant details.